# Перегрузка оператора класса

Tags: python

Нужно сделать перегрузку оператора +, аргументы: Convert или int, как лучше перегрузить?

```
class Convert:
    '''Класс для конвертации десятичных чисел в бинарные'''
    def __init__(self, dec: int) -> None:
        self.__dec: int = dec

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__dec}'
    
    def __add__(self, other: t.Union['Convert', int]) -> 'Convert':
        if isinstance(other, Convert):
            return Convert(self.__dec + other.__dec)
        return Convert(self.__dec + other)
```

Comment: но вы же уже написали перегрузку

Comment: @n1tr0xs а в плане использования isinstance правильно или можно как-то без него? Слышал эт моветон

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае использование `isinstance` нормально.

Есть лазейка связанная с волшебным методом `__int__`. Определяется преобразование вашего типа в целое. Для других типов не сработает:

```
class Convert:
    '''Класс для конвертации десятичных чисел в бинарные'''
    def __init__(self, dec: int) -> None:
        self.__dec: int = dec

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__dec}'

    def __int__(self) -> int:
        return self.__dec
    
    def __add__(self, other: t.Union['Convert', int]) -> 'Convert':
        return Convert(self.__dec + int(other))
```